# Counterclockwise spiral matrix

Tags: c++

Need to create a spiral matrix m * n, the elements of which are arranged counterclockwise m * n. The output should be something like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZ9HK.png).
My  code works only for arrays of the form n * n

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

const int n = 4;
static int arr[n][n];

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int numb = 0;
    for (int counter = 0; counter < n; ++counter) {
        for (int i = counter; i < n-counter; ++i) arr[i][counter] = ++numb;
        for (int j = counter+1; j < n-counter; ++j) arr[n-counter-1][j] = ++numb;
        for (int i = n-counter-2; i >= counter; --i) arr[i][n-counter-1] = ++numb;
        for (int j = n-counter-2; j > counter; --j) arr[counter][j] = ++numb;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) cout << setw(3) << arr[i][j];
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The needed change is so small and obvious that I find it difficult to believe that the person who wrote this code has to ask the question.

Comment: @Evg, Need to create a spiral matrix m * n, the elements of which are arranged counterclockwise m * n. My code doesnt work with, example, 10*4 arrayy, 
when m is not equal to n

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work when `m` is not equal to `n`? I don't see `m` in this code at all.

Comment: @Evg, I did not add it `const int n = 4;
const int m = 6;
static int arr[m][n]; `